# Should we use inline, tag name, or class selectors in CSS Documentation examples?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I came across [this proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/86253), which has some nice improvements, but primarily is just converting all `style=` examples into separate CSS stylesheet `div {...}` syntax.

For example:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    This div is too small to display its contents to display the effects of the overflow property.
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div>
    This div is too small to display its contents to display the effects of the overflow property.
</div>
```

with separate CSS

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

So I have a question, which of the following approaches makes the most sense?

1. Using the above `div{}` syntax? (Nobody would ever want such CSS to affect all `div`s so why write the example as such?)
2. Using a `.class` syntax for the stylesheet? (I think this is better than option #1)
3. Using inline `style=` syntax? This is the way the example was originally written.

Thoughts:

- I was initially in favor of keeping inline styles because it is easier for the newbie to understand and start using without modification.

  For one thing, they may not yet know how to create a separate CSS file, and this is not the place to teach them.
- Personally, I regularly use inline styles in cases where only one element is to be affected. Don't get me wrong.  I regularly use separate CSS Style Sheets as well. It depends on the nature of the project.

  Also it depends on the specific rule. For example, if I want custom colored text, or a simple `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, in many cases I will see no benefit to using the style sheet.
- We should also consider, for the advanced/productive programmer, which option serves better? Which option is more readable?

Comment: *"Best Practice"* (quotes definitely applicable) is obviously to separate form from styling. As you say there are cases where you might inline styles **for a specific reason** but for Examples...I'd say no.

Comment: I'd go for your #2. Inline styles get out of hand too quickly, especially when they're all munged together without spaces, as in your example. For one attribute? Maybe, but I still think having the separate CSS is more clear. When/if they implement Stack Snippets on Documentation, it will be much easier...

Comment: Don't write inline styles unless you're writing a topic on how to write inline styles. They're for overriding normal CSS which should exist in its own document or, in less than perfect situations, in the `<head>`. Plus it's just easier to separate the content thematically when reading and understand what is doing what if you have an HTML block and a CSS block.

Comment: I personally find separate css files/sections much easier to read than a super long inline rule.  For the example given, I'd approve/improve it.

Comment: I'm starting to agree with you guys, mainly because **inline style doesn't lend itself to multi-line syntax** so any time there are more than 2 or 3 rules it's going to be pretty obvious that we should use a separate style sheet. Consistency is important so I'm going to approve the change.

Comment: So the only question remains is whether to use #1 or #2 syntax above. Either way will work well with Stack Snippets. I'm leaning towards #2 for easier copy-paste ability. From the advanced programmer's perspective (i.e. people like myself) there's probably no difference between #1 and #2. That is what I'm thinking.

Comment: For me at least, I use inline styling for elements with 1 or 2 CSS rules. For more, it gets complicated to understand, so I'd prefer a separate sheet CSS rule. I think the class approach would be better, so that people wouldn't accidentally style all their tags when copying/pasting.

Comment: I mean, there's nothing stopping you from putting newlines in inline style attributes, but it *does* make the HTML a whole lot uglier. Also, I agree with what @TylerH said.

Answer (score 9):

Class names have the added benefit of being descriptive. You can assign a class called "example" to that particular element to make it clear to readers that this CSS rule is being applied to that specific HTML element as an illustration of that specific example.

You could even opt for an ID instead of a class, but then you'd get all the crazies yelling "IDs are bad practice" and somesuch. So perhaps it's better to just stick to classes and keep everyone happy.

> For one thing, they may not yet know how to create a separate CSS file, and this is not the place to teach them.

IMO, these examples should assume the reader already knows the difference between HTML and CSS well enough to understand that CSS can exist separately from HTML in one of a number of forms. In fact, I would consider inline style attributes an advanced topic that should be reserved only for examples that illustrate the use of that feature, such as examples illustrating how the inline style attribute of one element only affects that element, or how inline style declarations affect the cascade. In any other situation they are unnecessarily convoluted and hard to read, and should probably be avoided.

Examples are understood by most to be self-contained, so I don't think the locality of inline style attributes is a particularly important benefit.

Comment: "all the crazies" yes, they are crazy... IDs are great :-)

Comment: There are places to use classes, and there are places to use id, they almost never overlap. id isn't just classes that can only be one of, semantically they are very different thing.

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Tell that to the crazies. I'm not one of them.

Comment: I've never seen anyone claiming that id's are "bad practices"... maybe I go to the right places to read stuff.